# RegExp vs IRegExp2: class name confusion

Tags: excel, vba

Example:

```
Dim oRegEx As IRegExp2
Set oRegEx = New regexp
```

Alternative:

```
Dim oRegEx As regexp
Set oRegEx = New regexp
```

Both produce the same result, that is an object named "oRegEx" of type "RegExp/IRegExp2" as shown in the Type column of the Locals window.

The object browser for the library VBScript_RegExp_55 only shows the class "RegExp".

So, my questions are:
1) what is "IRegExp2"?
2) Should I prefer "IRegExp2" or "regexp" in the Dim line?
3) What are the different meanings of the first and the second name in the Type column of the Locals window?

Comment: Looks like the same thing to me. Once you initialize the `RegExp` and provoke an error 5018, you'll get a `Method 'Test' of object 'IRegExp2' failed` message to test that statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up the library via `oleview`, this is the IDL definition:

```
[
  uuid(3F4DACA4-160D-11D2-A8E9-00104B365C9F)
]
coclass RegExp {
    [default] interface IRegExp2;
};
```

The way VB6/VBA works; they exposes `coclass` as the first-class object, which is why you see `RegExp` in the object browser. However, you are not prevented from using the interfaces, which is why VBA/VB6 allows you to do `Dim foo As IRegExp2` and thus substitute the implementation with some other implementation (in theory, at least). Because the `RegExp` is the only implementation of the `IRegExp2` interface there is no practical difference. Had you created a class that implements `IRegExp2`, then it would make sense to declare variables as `IRegExp2` so that you have the freedom of using either the VBScript's implementation or your custom implementation.

Note that there is also a `IRegExp`. However, `IRegExp2` does not derive from it. Nonetheless, they are quite similar and you can assign it even though it's not explicitly stated so in the IDL:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim i1 As IRegExp
    Dim i2 As IRegExp2
    Dim o As RegExp

    Set o = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Set i2 = o
    Set i1 = o
End Sub
```

The reason why this works is so that you can have your old code that was originally written against the original RegExp 1.0 library continue to work using the RegExp 5.5 library without actually changing your code.

It is important to note that even though VBA/VB6 shows you coclasses, in fact you are always working with the COM interfaces under the hood. We can pretend that they are "class" because of the coclass having a default interface.